ChromeOS: Accessing ".local" hostnames from Linux container
I have a raspberry pi on my network with a hostname mypi.local. It has ssh and a little website running on it. It is connected to my WiFi network with DHCP.
My client device is a Chromebook. From a Chrome browser on the Chromebook, I can go to http://mypi.local and it connects to the website just fine. However, if I open up a Linux container and attempt to ssh to mypi.local, it says: ssh: Could not resolve hostname mypi.local: Name or service not known.
I can SSH to the device using its IP address, but since it's DHCP it's inconvenient. Is there a way to make ssh use the same resolving mechanism that the browser is using?

“Is there a way to make ssh use the same resolving mechanism that the browser is using?” - Host a DNS within your network that any device can use and point the host name to the device

@Ramhound that would certainly do it, but it's unnecessary. Turns out what makes this work is what Apple calls Bonjour and Linux calls zeroconf, and the Linux container didn't have a client that spoke that. See below.

Solved it. Turns out that mdns (aka Zeroconf, aka Bonjour) is not preinstalled in the linux container. I had to call sudo apt install libnss-mdns to get that support, then modify /etc/nsswitch.conf to have the line:
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns

And now I can SSH to the pi regardless of its IP address.
Credit goes to https://askubuntu.com/a/1437110/608531.
